# Visual studio 2015 / TFS Access is denied

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

When I try to **add new item** to project in visual studio 2015 I always get this message

> Access is denied.

The file is created and added to the project, but it is not added to Source Control, although the **project is in source control**. However, when I try to manually add the file to source control by right-clicking in Solution Explorer -> Add to source control, the file is added to TFS.

I have upgraded to windows 10 and installed Visual Studio 2015. I'm working on existing solution in C:\Projects\ and the solution was created and added to source control before I upgraded.

EDIT: If I run VS in admin mode, the error is gone

Comment: Which project you are working for?  As far as I can tell different projects have different root causes for error message:‘Access is denied’.

Comment: Wpf UserControl Library... Not sure what you are asking...

Comment: Because different project have different conditions due to the issue. Such as , if it occurs in a Web Application Project, it may caused by the right of worker process account . However,  if it occurs in a MVC Project , it may caused by another resaon.

Answer (score 3):

`Access is denied.` returns very little information. For more detail info, you can  repro the error  and run a procmon trace using Process Monitor tool filtered on DEVENV.EXE. Detail for how to use the tool: http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008024.aspx

Normally, this error message can be corrected with the followings:

1. Add your Windows account to  the Administrators group on the local PC
2. Run your Visual Studio in Administrator mode.
3. Check if your project folder is set to read only.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide more details, because I have deleted the folder where tfs project was mapped, and remapped it again, and the problem disappeared.

Running visual studio in admin mode worked, but that's not a solution.
My project folder was not readonly and I have granted full access rights to all users.